# The output is the same as input. How to fix?

Tags: c, utf-8, character-encoding

ANSI to UTF-8 converter. The main problem is that the output is the same as input. How to fix it?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
  FILE *SrcFile;
  FILE *DstFile;
  char ch;
  wchar_t wch;

    if((SrcFile = fopen("input.txt", "rb")) == NULL)
      return 1;
    if((DstFile = fopen("output.txt","wb+")) == NULL)
      return 1;

   fputc(0xFF, DstFile);
   fputc(0xFE, DstFile);

   while(TRUE)
   {
     ch = fgetc(SrcFile);
     if(feof(SrcFile))
       break;

     MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED,
       &ch, 1, &wch, 1);

     fputwc(wch, DstFile);
   }
   fclose(SrcFile);
   fclose(DstFile);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If hte input is ANSI, it will look the same as UTF-8. This is by design. It is only after the code points exceed 127, that UTF-8 will differ.
Also, you should not include a BOM (Byte Order Marker) in UTF-8 file content, as it is unnecessary.

Comment: Are you sure `&ch` is a `_In_NLS_string_(cbMultiByte)LPCCH`? *It looks a lot like a `char*` to me.* See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar

Comment: Also note that [MultiByteToWideChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) converts to **UTF-16**, not UTF-8 (of which ASCII is a subset).

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: Oh and you don't need that `feof` check. The `fgetc` function returns an `int` which will be `EOF` if there's an error or end of file. So you could use it directly in your loop condition `while ((ch = fgetc(SrcFile)) != EOF) { ... }`. Don't forget to define `ch` as an `int`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is a rare case of using `feof()` somewhat OK.  It still lacks detection of the rare case of `fgetc()` returning `EOF` due to error.  Aside from that, this form of testing `feof()` _after_ a `fgetc()` has advantages when `int` range is not a wider set of  `char` as `int` does not encoded all `unsigned char` + `EOF` values distinctly.   e.g. N-bit `unsigned char` and N-bit `int`.  Yet aside from such odd ball platforms, `while ((ch = fgetc(SrcFile)) != EOF) { ... }` is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

By design, the bottom 127 characters are binary compatible between ASCII/ANSI and UTF-8. so there should be no difference.

You should not include a BOM (Byte Order Marker) in UTF-8 file content, as it is unnecessary because the byte-stream for UTF-8 is unique so doesn't need to deal with "endian" issues. Also, adding the BOM may break some applications that accept ANSI.

Comment: ANSI characters range goes up to 255.

Comment: True, but, in most Latin text cases, the actual values used stay in the bottom 127 which corresponds to Unicode Basic-Latin. Higher code points in ANSI generally represent uncommon punctuation, Mathematical symbols and accented Latin characters.

Comment: It can work for Latin based alphabets if there are no symbols. But it will fail for non-Latin alphabets such as Greek, Cyrillic, Asian languages...

Comment: Those aren't supported in ISO 8859-1 which is the formal definition of ANSI.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you can convert from ANSI to UTF16, then convert from UTF16 to UTF8.

You cannot convert between character sets 1 byte at a time. The whole file must be read in to buffer, and converted. Note that each Unicode code point is between 1 to 4 bytes in UTF8, while it is 2 or 4 bytes in UTF16, and always 1 byte in ANSI.

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE* src = fopen("source.txt", "rb");
    if(!src) return 0;

    FILE* dst = fopen("destination.txt", "wb");
    if(!dst) return 0;

    fseek(src, 0, SEEK_END);
    long filesize = ftell(src);
    char *ansi = malloc(filesize);

    fseek(src, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(ansi, 1, filesize, src);

    int codepage = CP_ACP;
    int u16size = MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, ansi, filesize, NULL, 0);
    wchar_t *u16 = malloc(u16size * sizeof(wchar_t));
    MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, ansi, filesize, u16, u16size);

    int u8size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, u16, u16size, NULL, 0, NULL, FALSE);
    char *u8 = malloc(u8size);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, u16, u16size, u8, u8size, NULL, FALSE);

    fwrite(u8, 1, u8size, dst);

    return 0;
}
```